# CSS resize block proportionally

Tags: javascript, css

I made a decrease in the block when the width of the screen decreases, but I can’t do anything to make it decrease with a decrease in height, how can this be done?................................................................................................................................................................................................................

[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/kepamuk/wc91xo4b/

html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar"></div>
<div class="scaleable-wrapper" id="scaleable-wrapper">

    <div class="very-specific-design" id="very-specific-design">

        <h1>I am designed just so.</h1>

        <p>My design is intentional. I want to be scaled in such a way that scales the design. No reflows or anything,
            just straight up scaling. Kinda like SVG.</p>

        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/skull-and-crossbones.svg" alt=""/>

        <p class="bigred"> ✖ ✖ ✖ </p>

    </div>

</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var $wrapper = $("#scaleable-wrapper");
    var $el = $("#very-specific-design");
    var elWidth = $el.outerWidth();
    var elHeight = $el.outerHeight();

    $(window).resize(function () {
      size();
    });
    size();

    function size() {
      var scale;
      console.log('$wrapper.width()', $wrapper.width())
      console.log('elWidth', elWidth)
      console.log('$wrapper.height()', $wrapper.height())
      console.log('elHeight', elHeight)
      scale = Math.min(
        $wrapper.width() / elWidth,
        $wrapper.height() / elHeight
      );

      $el.css({
        transform: "translate(-50%, -50%) " + "scale(" + scale + ")"
      });
    }

  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
    background: #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 40px 40px 40px 100px;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar{
    background-color: grey;
    width: 40px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.very-specific-design {
    width: 877px;
    height: 593px;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

.scaleable-wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #666;
    height: 593px;
}

.ui-resizable-se {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: orange;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.bigred {
    color: red;
    font-size: 5rem;
}
```

**My solution**

I added

```
height: calc(100vh - 80px);
```

to .scaleable-wrapper but maybe there is a better option

Comment: Your solution seems to be the correct one as at first `height` was fixed at `593px` while `width` is html default `auto`. As "px" is a "fixed" and not a "relative" unit it resulted in a non-scaling height. By using "vh" you made it relative, hense scaling. Read [MDN relative units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Relative_length_units), something that needs to be saved in the back of your head...